# Spring Security and Angular 5

Tags: spring-security, angular5

Right now I'm sending username and password through header from my angular 5 app after successful login to access spring rest api. After Successful I'm getting unique sessionId from spring in response can I use that ID instead of credentials to authenticate

angular code

```
  let d=localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
let headers = new Headers();
    var user=JSON.parse(d);
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    // creating base64 encoded String from user name and password
    var base64Credential: string = btoa(user.principal.username+ ':' + user.principal.password);
    headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Credential);

    let options = new RequestOptions({  headers: headers 
    });

    var self = this;
    self.greeting = {id:'', content:''};
    http.get(this.url,options).map(response => self.greeting = response.json);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jwt token for this.

- Store the sessionId in localStorage or a cookie.
- Send it inside the request header in each and every request (use httpInteceptor for this)
  https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8
- In the Java application, add filter to all the requests, which need to be protected.